# `chmod g+s` returns success even though it actually fails, and only works as root

Tags: permissions, chmod

`ls -l cgi-bin` returns `drwxr----- 3 user http 4096 Mar 16 22:35 cgi-bin`. After doing `chmod g+s cgi-bin`, it returns success but nothing happens. What could be the cause of this? (if i try edit read/write/execute permission it works)

Edit:Turns out it works if i do `sudo chmod g+s cgi-bin` instead. But why does it not work when doing it as `user` and why does it return success when it doesn't actually work?

Comment: Can you add the commands you issued to your question, including those you used to check? And can you run `id` to confirm your ID, and check ownership and permissions of cgi-bin's parent?

Comment: I tried it. In a directory that I own, I ran `mkdir cgi-bin; chmod 700 cgi-bin; chmod g+s cgi-bin` and it turned out to have permissions `drwx--S---`. This is on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: On which *system* are you running, and as which *user* are you trying to `chmod`? What displays if you type `echo $?` after the failing `chmod`?

Comment: @Totor arch linux. It only happens on `/srv/http` and subfolders. I run `chmod` as `user` which is the default user and current owner of the folder (original owner was `root` but i did `chgroup` to change its ownership to `user`). As i said, it returned success, therefore `echo $?` returns `0`. I use `ls -l` to check permissions.